# Incompatible with sql_mode:only_full_group_by

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have this query :

```
select p.id from product p 
            join product_variant pv on pv.product_id = p.id
            JOIN channel_pricing pr on pr.product_variant_id = pv.id
            WHERE p.id in (1,2,3,4,5) and p.main_taxon_id = 2
            GROUP BY pv.product_id
            ORDER BY pr.price ASC
```

I'm getting this error :

> Expression #1 of ORDER BY clause is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'sidratsoft_flora_db.pr.price' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Is there a way to fix it without changing the `sql_mode`?

Comment: For each Product id, you may have to apply the group functions like sum,avg etc on pr.price.

Comment: Fix: change `SELECT p.id` to `SELECT pv.product_id AS id` and `ORDER BY pr.price` to `ORDER BY MAX(pr.price)`

Comment: *dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=44fa997cf1a0efa27d6bb3567df4e712)*